# Need REGEX_REPLACE syntax to replace only 10digit number in a string statement

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am looking equivalent hive query syntax to replace specified length of number with some string or empty.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('blaa blaa 1234380934 enter', '([[:digit:]]{10})', 'xxxxxxxxxx')
```

Expected Value : `blaa blaa xxxxxxxxxx enter`

Can some one please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('blaa blaa 1234380934 enter', '\\d{10}', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
```

Result:

```
blaa blaa xxxxxxxxxx enter
```